# How to publish to Azure Functions Runtime

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

An Azure Functions Runtime blog post (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions-runtime-preview/) states the following:

> It provides an endpoint that allows you to publish your functions from
>   Microsoft Visual Studio, Team Foundation Server, or Visual Studio Team
>   Services.

I cannot find any examples of how to publish to a local instance of Azure Functions Runtime instead of the Azure cloud. Preferably I would like to publish a pre-compiled Azure Function using the Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can publish your Functions to Azure Functions Runtime preview by downloading the publishing profile from the portal and then importing it in Visual Studio 2015 in the Publish... dialog:

[image]

[image]

Regarding the VS2017 tooling support, currently there is no way to import the publishing settings into the Publish dialog.  We are currently working with the VS team on this.

Answer (score 3):

*From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference*

### How to update function app files

The function editor built into the Azure portal lets you update the `function.json` file and the code file for a function. To upload or update other files such as `package.json` or `project.json` or dependencies, you have to use other deployment methods.

Function apps are built on App Service, so all the [deployment options available to standard web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy) are also available for function apps. Here are some methods you can use to upload or update function app files.

**To use App Service Editor**

1. In the Azure Functions portal, click Function app settings.
2. In the Advanced Settings section, click Go to App Service Settings.
3. Click App Service Editor in App Menu Nav under DEVELOPMENT TOOLS.
4. click Go.
5. After App Service Editor loads, you'll see the `host.json` file and function folders under `wwwroot`.
6. Open files to edit them, or drag and drop from your development machine to upload files.

**To use the function app's SCM (Kudu) endpoint**

1. Navigate to: `https://<function_app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`.
2. Click Debug Console > CMD.
3. Navigate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\` to update `host.json` or `D:\home\site\wwwroot\<function_name>` to update a function's files.
4. Drag-and-drop a file you want to upload into the appropriate folder in the file grid. There are two areas in the file grid where you can drop a file. For .zip files, a box appears with the label "Drag here to upload and unzip." For other file types, drop in the file grid but outside the "unzip" box.

**To use FTP**

1. Follow the instructions here to get FTP configured.
2. When you're connected to the function app site, copy an updated `host.json` file to `/site/wwwroot` or copy function files to `/site/wwwroot/<function_name>`.

**To use continuous deployment**

Follow the instructions in the topic [Continuous deployment for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment).

---

*From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview*

### Azure Functions Runtime Overview

The Azure Functions Runtime provides a new way for you to take advantage of the simplicity and flexibility of the Azure Functions programming model on-premises. Built on the same open source roots as Azure Functions, Azure Functions Runtime is deployed on-premises to provide a nearly identical development experience as the cloud service.

The Azure Functions Runtime consists of two pieces:

- Azure Functions Runtime Management Role
- Azure Functions Runtime Worker Role

### Azure Functions Management Role

The Azure Functions Management Role provides a host for the management of your Functions on-premise. This role performs the following tasks:

- Hosting of the Azure Functions Management Portal, which is the the same one you see in the Azure portal. This lets you develop your functions in the same way as you would in the Azure portal.
- Distributing functions across multiple Functions workers.
- Providing a publishing endpoint so that you can publish your functions direct from Microsoft Visual Studio.

If you read the [MSDN blog link that you provided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/), I think both your questions are answered there. (Although you will have to point to the local (on-premises) rather than the cloud (Azure).

---

### How to publish a Function project to Azure directly from Visual Studio

> To publish a Function project to Azure directly from Visual Studio,
>   right click the project and choose “Publish”. On the publish page, you
>   can either create a new Function App in Azure or publish to an
>   existing one. Note: even though the Folder option is currently
>   appears, it’s not intended for use with Azure Functions at this time.

---

### How to locally deploy a Function project in Visual Studio

> To add a function to the application right click the project and
>   choose “Add Item”, then choose the “Azure Function” item template.
>   This will launch the Azure Function dialog that enables you to choose
>   the type of function you want, and enter any relevant binding
>   information. For example, in the dialog below, the queue trigger asks
>   you for the name of the function, the name of the connection string to
>   the storage queue, and the name of the queue (path)
>
> This generates a new class that has the following elements:
>
> - A static Run method, that is attributed with [FunctionName] attribute.
>     The [FunctionName] attribute indicates that the method is the entry
>     for an Azure Function.
> - The first parameter has a QueueTrigger
>     attribute, this is what indicates is a queue trigger function (and
>     takes the binding information as parameters to the attribute. In this
>     case the name of the queue and the connection string’s setting name)
>
> Once you have a function, local development works like you would
>   expect. You can run and debug it locally, add NuGet packages, create
>   unit tests, and anything else you would do for a class library.

Comment: The first point allows you to create a publish profile to publish to the cloud, it does not allow you to publish to a local instance of Azure Functions Runtime. The second point allows me to debug and run the function in visual studio, it does not allow me to run the function on the azure functions runtime. My goal is to host the function in Azure Functions Runtime so that I can run tests against the local instance.

Comment: I'm looking the last section `Once you have a function, local development works like you would expect. You can run and debug it locally, add NuGet packages, create unit tests, and anything else you would do for a class library.` I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not looking to do local development, I'm looking to use the Azure Functions Runtime to host the Function on premise. I can currently create functions manually on premise using the on premise portal. I cannot however publish my project to the on premise host, I can only publish to the cloud.

Comment: The Azure Functions Runtime is a framework to run Azure Functions on premise. _This runtime provides a new way for customers to take advantage of the Functions programming model on-premises. Built on the same open source roots that Azure Functions service is built on, Azure Functions Runtime can be deployed on-premises and provides a near similar development experience as the cloud service._

Comment: Well, that makes it pretty easy. You'd just point to a the Azure Functions Runtime on your local machine, rather than the one hosted in the cloud, No? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview

Comment: I have tried modifying a pubxml to point to the local instance of Azure Functions Runtime but I am unable to get this to work. The standard dialogs do not show a way to target an on premise instance, they prompt for Azure Subscription.

Comment: I know it is preview but the blog post specifically states that _It provides an endpoint that allows you to publish your functions from Microsoft Visual Studio_

Comment: I've updated the post to show you the ways to connect to the endpoint. I think this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and see if I can get it going